# video shortcode not working in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to add mp4 video to my page, but shortcode [video] not workig. I see only string in frontend with:

```
[video width="640" height="360" mp4="http://localhost:8080/CC/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/movie.mp4"]
```

Where is the problem ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using ? The [video] shortcode is added in 3.6.

Comment: This is the newest version of WordPress 4.2.2

Comment: Try disabling all plugins and on wordpress standard theme. A screenshot of  front end will be helpful after that

Comment: Any answers to this issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the closing shortcode tag `[/video]` like this

```
[video width="640" height="360" mp4="http://localhost:8080/CC/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/movie.mp4"][/video]
```

its shoudnt be a requirement but just in case try it let us know.

Comment: @Robson If you go directly to the mp4 source location directly in the browser it works right ?

Comment: Yes, when i copy and paste to browser url I see video.

Comment: @Robson Did you also upload that video via the Wordpress Media page? Did it give u any errors, maybe use the generated link there? Also maybe check your logs in Apache maybe its something related to the server itself. Try turning debug on in the `wp-config.php` with this line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` also.

Answer (score 0):

You neglected the short-code. You wrote **mp4** instead of **src**

*Code corrected*:

```
[video width="640" height="360" src="http://localhost:8080/CC/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/movie.mp4"]
```

Comment: According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode `mp4=` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The updated link is [https://wordpress.org/support/article/video-shortcode/](https://wordpress.org/support/article/video-shortcode/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was seeing a normal link to the video instead of the video element.

Removing the `playsinline` attribute from the video tag (which had been added via a PHP filter in my functions.php file) and making sure the video format was correct fixed the issue for me.